# How to fix an audio or lib linking issue?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I'm having a problem with a steam game - it has no audio. When I launch it from the terminal, a part I see is this:

```bsh
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:339:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so (/usr/lib/libsndfile.so.1: undefined symbol: ogg_stream_pageout_fill)
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such device or address
```

I'm using manjaro cinnamon currently.

This game worked on manjaro xfce previously (same exact hardware I'm using now). All other audio on my system works. Other steam games the audio works.

I've tried:

- verifying game files
- installing on manjaro xfce
- some things described in archwiki for steam problems
- posting on manjaro forums, posting on steam, emailing the creators of the game
- googling various pieces of the error message

I don't know which libs steam is using, as it looks like they have their own?

Comment: If you install `pacman -S lib32-libpulse`, does this fix your issue?

Comment: Can you post the output of `aplay -l`?